# Ansible XML Module adding nested children

Tags: xml, xpath, ansible

I'm setting up a ansible project for an aws infrastructure and need to edit multiple XML files, mostly adding nested elements. After some time I got an example running which was harder then I expected.

```
- name: HTTPS Config - Add SSLConfig to VHost.xml
  xml:
    path: /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/conf/VHost.xml
    xpath: "/descendant::HostPort[1]"
    pretty_print: Yes
    add_children:
      - SSLConfig:
          _:
            - KeyStorePath: Censored
            - KeyStorePassword: 'XXXXXX'
            - CipherSuites: "{{ ciphersuites }}"
            - Protocols: 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2'
  when: wowza_install.changed
```

This results in adding the nested element at the end of the first HostPort element, formatted

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root version="2">
    <VHost>
        <Description></Description>
        <HostPortList>
            <HostPort>
                <!-- Many more stuff -->
                <Port>1935</Port>
                <HTTPIdent2Response></HTTPIdent2Response>
                <SSLConfig>
                    <KeyStorePath>Censored</KeyStorePath>
                    <KeyStorePassword>XXXXXX</KeyStorePassword>
                    <SSLProtocol>TLS</SSLProtocol>
                    <CipherSuites>List_of_CipherSuites</CipherSuites>
                    <Protocols>TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2</Protocols>
                </SSLConfig>
            </HostPort>
            <!-- More HostPort definitions -->
        </HostPortList>
    </VHost>
</Root>
```

The first issue now (more or less) is that the second example "HTTPS Config - Logging SSL" inserts the xml unformatted, even though I gave the option `pretty_print: Yes`. This works nicely for the previous example "HTTPS Config - Add SSLConfig to VHost.xml", where the inserted XML is formatted correctly.

```
- name: HTTPS Config - Logging SSL
  xml:
    path: /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/conf/Server.xml
    xpath: "/descendant::Server/Properties"
    pretty_print: Yes
    add_children:
      - Name: 'sslLogConnectionInfo'
      - Value: 'false'
      - Type: 'Boolean'
  when: wowza_install.changed
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root version="2">
    <Server>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Description>Description</Description>

        <!-- all kind of stuff which is not relevant -->
        <Properties>
                   <Name>sslLogConnectionInfo</Name><Value>false</Value><Type>Boolean</Type></Properties>
    </Server>
</Root>
```

The second and more annoying part is that rerunning my ansible project adds the xml tag a second time, which I avoided by registering `woza_install` when fetching a new setup. I tried `set_children` instead of `add_children`, but this overwrites all existing children within the element. Since I'm rather new to xpaths I assumed that my mistake is selecting all children of the "wanted" element ("/descendant::"), which then get deleted by the `set_children`.

So any suggestions on what I'm missing are welcomed.

Comment: Should `<Name>` be a child of `<Properties>`? Or should there be a `<Property>` element wrapping those values?

Comment: `<Properties>` should wrap the values, as it is displayed in the example. But the question is why is ansible adding it unformatted but formats it on the other example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however using

```
your_inventory_variable | checksum
```

Then I store the result somewhere:

```
- name: "Generate current checksum value"
  community.general.xml:
    path: /path/to/xml.xml
    xpath: "/path/to/checksum_property"
    value:  "{{ your_inventory_variable | checksum }}"
    pretty_print: yes
  when: virtualip.interfaces is defined
  register: config_checksum
```

Once this is done, you can just use add_children with this condition:

```
when: config_checksum.changed
```

Before that you have to clean the structure of course, in that way you will avoid adding same stuff again and again.